# Service: Task Queue

Tags: queue, cloud, task

Does anyone know of a paid service that allows you to load up queue of url based tasks that are then run in realtime? I'm looking at setting up a local task queue, but I'm willing to pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

[Beanstalkd](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd) is easy enough to install on Linux, or there is a SAAS compatible version - http://www.iron.io/products/mq

Beyond that, Amazon SQS has various libraries that make it quite easy to use, though it uses HTTP to get/set items in the queue, so it has an additional overhead.